# Method to estimate prior growth of directory size vs. time on Windows

Tags: file-management, perl

I would like to know how fast a directory grew previously over time, so I can figure out what disk space I need in the future. Is there a way to make a list with file size in column 1 and creation date in column 2, for all files contained in a directory and its subdirectory? [I can then plot the cumulative sum of file size vs prior time]. Background: the directory is on a Windows machine, the files don't tend to get modified after they are created, and my rough estimate is the directory is growing 600 GB per month.

Comment: Directory size here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813826/get-folder-size-from-windows-command-line

Comment: I am actually looking for the past history of how the directory size has increased vs. time, rather than the directory size at the present or into the future. Sorry this was not clear originally. I updated the title and text to better reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need an easy solution, I would recommend you PowerShell.

You can use this command: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\something -File -Recurse | Select Length,CreationTime`

Just replace `C:\something` with your path.

You can create whole script from it and use Windows scheduler to run it in desired frequency.

Script should then:

1. Get information (actual sizes and sizes saved in last run).
2. Calculate difference.
3. Save information.